# Fondo no ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, fondo

Soy nuevo en esto del desarrollo web y tengo un ligero problema: hice una sección de servicios pero el fondo no ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla. Quizá suene como una pregunta estúpida, agradeceré toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Así se ven hasta ahorita:
[image]

[image]

```
   /*Services section*/
   .services-title:before {
     content: "";
     background: #2851c2;
     height: 5px;
     width: 200px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     display: block;
     transform: translateY(45px);
   }

       #services {
         background: #e7e7e7;
         background-size: cover;
         margin-top: 11px;
         padding-top: 30px;
         padding-bottom: 60px;
         padding: 0;
       }
```

El html es este:

```
div class="text-center">
  <h3 class="services-title">Mis servicios</h3>
  <section id="services">
    <div class="services-detail">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
          <div class="services-selection">
            <div class="services-icon">
              <img src="images/servicios/evaluación.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="services-description">
              <h4></h4>
              <p></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Samuel fíjate de poner la clase `container-fluid` después de `services-detail` para tener la syntax de bootstrap de que un container tiene rows y cols.

Answer (score 1):

Según entendí quieres hacer algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<style>
    .bg-degradado{
        background: rgba(73,155,234,1);
        height: 100px;
    }
    .bg-gray{
        background-color: gray;
    }

    .titulo_servicios{
        border-bottom: solid 3px rgba(73,155,234,1);
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    .mt-100{
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row mt-100">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="titulo_servicios text-center mx-auto">Mis servicios</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                icono evaluacion
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row bg-degradado">
        </div>

        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
            <!-- 
                la clase d-flex justify-content-center te alineara los divs que tengas al centro.
            -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aXeEbNJ.png" alt="">
                <h3> titulo </h3>
                <p>
                    Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne
                     lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aXeEbNJ.png" alt="">
                <h3> titulo </h3>
                <p>
                    Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne
                     lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aXeEbNJ.png" alt="">
                <h3> titulo </h3>
                <p>
                    Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne
                     lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​.
                </p>
            </div>
           

        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="titulo_servicios text-center mx-auto">Mis servicios</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center bg-gray">
            <!-- 
                la clase d-flex justify-content-center te alineara los divs que tengas al centro.
            -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aXeEbNJ.png" alt="">
                <h3> titulo </h3>
                <p>
                    Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne
                     lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aXeEbNJ.png" alt="">
                <h3> titulo </h3>
                <p>
                    Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne
                     lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aXeEbNJ.png" alt="">
                <h3> titulo </h3>
                <p>
                    Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne
                     lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​.
                </p>
            </div>
           

        </div>

    </div>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Lo hice pero sigue igual, alguna idea? ;(

Comment: puedes poner una captura de toda el sitio web ? y marca la sección que deseas que tome todo el ancho.

Comment: Listo, ya la puse ;)

Comment: @samuel088 edite mi respuesta, te puse una estructura del html según tu imagen, solo tendrias que agregar las separaciones correspondientes, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

```
#services{
/* La imagen de fondo se reescala automáticamente con el cambio del ancho de ventana del navegador */
    background-size: cover;
    /* Para que la imagen de fondo no se repita */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Donde se encuentra la Imagen*/
    background-image: url(imagenes/fondos/ssolar.png);
}
```

en background-image: url(imagenes/fondos/ssolar.png); añade tu direccion de imagen y lo mete dentro de tu fondo

Answer (score -1):

Podrias usar algo asi:

```css
 background: url(https://cdn.memegenerator.es/imagenes/memes/full/0/15/151873.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score -2):

**Edición**

Úse container-fluid para un contenedor de ancho completo, que abarca todo el ancho de su viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   ...
</div>
```

Fuente : [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/)
Saludos :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración, pero, el fondo que quiero lo estoy identificando en el css(background: #e7e7e7) ;, no es el "evaluación.png" :(

Comment: Agrega entonces, a las clases que mencioné, lo siguiente. background-color: #12091c y pruebalo.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Perdón, entendí mal la pregunta, chechalo ahora :)

Comment: Aún nada bro, creo que lo dejaré sin fondo ya que no encuentro alguna solución, igual muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda <3

Comment: Lo mas lógico aquí es que un componente superior esté afectando la clase, busca que elemento afecta que tu componente. Otras causa (me pasa a menudo) es que el navegador carga la clase y no refleja el cambio, mi solución es borrar la cache de manera forzada (Ctrl + Mayús + R )

Comment: Bro, ya vi, tengo otro container, sí quisiera agregar este otro container cómo haría para diferenciarlos class="container1" o algo así ?